# Guniorn is not showing multiple django sites

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I am hosting a website on Ubuntu VPS using Gunicorn. My first website is working fine but when I am trying to use same settings for the second website it is giving me error "BAD REQUEST 400". For the first site I am not using virtual environment. But for the second site I am using virtual environment. Following are my settings for gunciorn with both sites.

Site1 settings are:

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project with no virtual environment"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec gunicorn \
    --name=django_project \
    --pythonpath=django_project \
    --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    django_project.wsgi:application
```

My second site settings are like:

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project with virtual environment"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectedly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django/venv

exec venv/bin/gunicorn \
    --name=django_project2\
    --pythonpath=django_project2\
    --bind=127.0.0.1:9500 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    django_project2.wsgi:application
```

My first site with no virtual env hosted under Django user folder `(/home/django/django_project)`. My second site is hosted at location `(/home/django/venv/django_project2)`. I can connect my second site with port 9500 but not the domain name with command `gunicorn --bind domain.com:9500 domain.wsgi:application`. But I cannot bind by bypassing port. I think the only thing that is different that in new project I am using virtualenv. Can anyone help that why it is not working in virtualenv? Also with when I use command "gunicorn django_project2.wsgi:application --bind domain.com 9500" I can open up my domain typing the port number like domain.com:9500. But when I use 127.0.0.1:9500 it is not binding correctly. Please advise what changes needs to take place for virtualenv and also if I am using wrong parameters for binding with gunicorn.

Comment: Add `--error-logfile /path/to/error.log` to gunicorn command, and see if you can find out the error your app is throwing.

Comment: How do I suppose to record logs when domain is not connecting?

Comment: Are you sure it's not connecting? what's returning the "BAD REQUEST 400" in your question?

Comment: its a way to check it on Linux with command "curl -I anydomainname.com".

Comment: I think you have DEBUG disabled and you haven't added you domain to ALLOWED_HOSTS. Quick test is to set ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']

Comment: My domain is added in ALLOWD_HOST = ['domain.com', 'www.domain.com']. DEBUG = False.